# Transcriber software for Windows?

Tags: video, audio, plain-text, speech-recognition, transcription

Suppose that I am watching some educational movies. for example a course on a university that has been published on the web and I want to write a pamphlet for my self.

Since I'm not in the classroom and not in a hurry, I try to write all the lecture word by word and try not to miss anything. It takes a lot of time.

And sometimes there are really useful lectures that are not in English (mostly German,French or Spanish lectures), translating the voice to English to English is more difficult than translating a text in those languages to English.

So I'm searching for a transcriber software:

- That is very exact in English (I just want to watch the lecture and after being finished, just correct little mistakes and add some diagrams, etc. of the lecture to the text and store it as a pamphlet)
- It also supports the other 3 main European languages and is exact enough.(If you know any individual software for each of these languages, please introduce them, too)
- I know that most of such softwares, won't support a language like persian, but if there's any I'd be happy to hear its name.
- It should be able to dictate text from audio or video (I can convert videos to audio) not just from the microphone.

The cost of the program or being free or not, is not very important. I just want to get familiar.

Please don't tell me to use auto cc of YouTube, etc. I can't upload all of those huge files.

Comment: If youtube's autocc were to produce an acceptable transcription (which it has never done any of the times I've tried it), I believe you could copy the script text and paste it wherever you want.

Comment: @aparente001 yes, you're right. `.srt` is convertible to `.txt`. I have updated the question.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant for you, but in case it does: https://www.tunestotube.com/ is great for uploading audio only to youtube.

Comment: I think you would need to train your own neural network to recognize voice, fortunately mozilla has been doing a project to create a dataset
Yes, even in persian https://commonvoice.mozilla.org/fa/datasets
Here is a guide on how to do it yourself https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lITdVShy7gEqNdQmc4yraj38sV7PiagX

I know it's not much, but at least you have tools that help you do this yourself if you ever so desire.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend https://transcribe.wreally.com for transcribing.  You can use it with any language.  You use it in the Chrome browser but you don't have to be connected to the internet while using it.

If you want to use their voice recognition feature (which I haven't tried), their website says you can use the following languages: English, Español, Portuguese, Chinese (Simplied, Traditional and Cantonese), Arabic, Català, Deutsch, Français, Hebrew, Hindi, Italiano, Japanese, Korean, Nederlands, Româna and Russian.

Comment: Note that as of November 2020, this software is free for 1 week, and then requires payment to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest Microsoft tools embed in Office 365:

[image]

A killer-class software as for me. I have never seen so far a better and less error-prone transcribe-like solution.